# Can't Access SharePoint Online Programmatically Anymore

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

A week ago I was able to access SharePoint Online programmatically through a c# application. Now I am getting the following error:

```
The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.
```

**I can access the SharePoint site in my browser completely fine.**

I tried accessing it through SharePoint Online Management Shell but I get the same error when doing the following:

```
$adminUPN="name@business.com"
$userCredential = Get-Credential -UserName $adminUPN -Message "Type the password."
Connect-SPOService -Url https://business.sharepoint.com/sites/bd/resume/ -Credential $userCredential
```

When I try and connect without the credentials using:

```
Connect-SPOService -Url https://business.sharepoint.com/sites/bd/resume/
```

It firstly pops up a Microsoft Sign in window to enter just my username/email, which looks normal. But when I enter my email, click next it takes me to different sign in page which looks off (See screenshot below, I removed company information with black scribble).

[image: Password login]

After I enter my password and hit enter I get a different error:

```
Connect-SPOService : Could not authenticate to SharePoint Online https://business.sharepoint.com/sites/bd/resume/ using OAuth 2.0
```

---

Firstly, I want to confirm if this is a problem on my end or if this a problem with permission, etc on the admin end.

Answer (score 1):

The cause for your issue could be the fact that the **LegacyAuthProtocolsEnabled** property, at tenant level, is set to **False**. Setting the value of this property to **True** can solve the issue.

To get the current value run the following command in PowerShell:

```
 Connect-SPOService

 Get-SPOTenant
```

To set the value to True for **LegacyAuthProtocolsEnabled**  run the following commands in PowerShell:

```
 Connect-SPOService

 Set-SPOTenant -LegacyAuthProtocolsEnabled $True
```

After you run the commands it's necessary to wait some time until will work.

According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/Set-SPOTenant?view=sharepoint-ps), a value of False prevents Office clients using non-modern authentication protocols from accessing SharePoint Online resources.

A value of True- Enables Office clients using non-modern authentication protocols (such as, Forms-Based Authentication (FBA) or Identity Client Runtime Library (IDCRL)) to access SharePoint resources.

Comment: I can't connect using Connect-SPOService, get 503 error

Comment: Can you check the "Access control" settings in tenant admin site (like http://[yourtenant]-admin.sharepoint.com) ? Do you have block access set under "Unmanaged devices" or "Apps that don't use modern authentication"? Do you access the SharePoint under a user which is global admin?

Comment: both settings are set to Allow